# Get server timestamp after batch.commit() with Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

After writing a batch of documents on Firestore, how to get the timestamp stored in the database? For each document saved, there is a field like the following.

```
data = {
   timestamp: serverTimestamp()
}
```

After writing the batch, I get something like:

```
timestamp: 
  __PRIVATE_ServerTimestampFieldValueImpl
  _methodName: "serverTimestamp"
  [[Prototype]]: FieldValue
```

Is it mandatory to read the data to get the server timestamp or is there a way to get it when writing the batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it mandatory to read the data to get the server timestamp or is there a way to get it when writing the batch?

Yes, this is true for all writes and not just batches, and it is true for all client SDKs.

The timestamp is calculated on the Firestore backend, so you need to reach back into the backend in order to get that value.  This requires reading the document after it's written.